# HTML5 canvas object events

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a way to attach an event handler to a object drawn on HTML5 Canvas, without tracking the points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try Kinetic JS

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

Comment: While Kinetic will allow you to (seemingly) attach event handlers to canvas elements, it's designed for animations, and as a result will constantly redraw the page. If you have a complex (lots of objects) canvas, these redraws may slow your canvas right down to the point of unusability.

Comment: As of version 3, KineticJS now intelligently draws only the objects that have moved.  In addition, it's MUCH faster than earlier versions.  Here's an example of a tooltip stress test using 10,000 shapes: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-10000-shape-stress-test-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 4):

You might also take a look at KineticJS - it was designed to make attaching event listeners to shapes on the screen as simple as possible while sticking to Canvas API patterns.  You can check out an example here:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cake](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/canvas.html#KeyboardTest). It's a scene graph plug-in for canvas elements. You should be able to attach event handlers to canvas objects with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is (but no other poster is using the term) that there is no first-class support for events on graphic primitives drawn on HTML5 canvas. That is not to say that it is not possible to write a listener, merely that if you want to do that you have to use an API like Kinetic JS as can be seen at

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

Answer (score 1):

I think, KineticJS should suffice for most of your needs. But make sure that you keep HTML5 originated events away from KineticJS events. I am facing some issues on these lines. will update you if I find something.
Regards