# Best way to make image interactive

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to make "game" played from browser (fullscreen or not), where will be shown only photo with posibility to interact with object on it. Like pickup something, open etc.

What is best way to do it?

Use only html(5), javascript etc or something like Flash?

Thank you very much for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use html5 canvas technology, there is a library called [Kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/), which allows you to put event listeners to independent objects on canvas screen, such as putting drag&drop support for a circle drawed into canvas.

Comment: Canvas elements support events by default. I would recommend using a framework, but it's not required.

Comment: If you have read my question properly, you would have noticed that I actually recommended a framework/library, that supports events.

Comment: Where is your question? I think you missed my point. Sure, KineticJS supports events, but so does any other framework because events are nativly available. Your answer is misleading at best.

Comment: How canvas supports event handling to individual shapes drawn into it? can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought this was part of the native API. I guess it isn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766313/html5-canvas-object-events

Comment: Yes, indeed! That was the most challenging part implementing interactive apps using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a solution that uses `canvas` but maybe just simple `svg` is enough. Both solutions involve JavaScript. HTML5 means nothing.

I would not recommend Flash because of compatibility issues.